# Saving from array to another array - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I did save value to an object mapper called
`var testing:[Test]?`
By using this code

```
let test: Test = Test()! 


var i = 0
    while i < self.array.count{
        let test: Test = Test()!
        test.userId = self.array[i]
        print(test.userId)
        test.firstName = self.array[i+1]
        test.lastName = self.array[i+2]
        test.img1 = self.array[i+3]
        test.img2 = self.array[i+4]
        test.img3 = self.array[i+5]
        test.featuredImg1 = self.array[i+6]
        test.url1 = self.array[i+7]
        test.featuredImg2 = self.array[i+8]
        test.url2 = self.array[i+9]
        test.featuredImg3 = self.array[i+10]
        test.url3 = self.array[i+11]
        test.userId2 = self.array[i+12]
        test.firstName2 = self.array[i+13]
        test.lastName2 = self.array[i+14]
        test.img4 = self.array[i+15]
        test.img5 = self.array[i+16]
        test.img6 = self.array[i+17]
        test.featuredImg4 = self.array[i+18]
        test.url4 = self.array[i+19]
        test.featuredImg5 = self.array[i+20]
        test.url5 = self.array[i+21]
        test.featuredImg6 = self.array[i+22]
        test.url6 = self.array[i+23]

        i = i + 24


        testing?.append(test)

    }
    print(testing?.count)
```

Which is not working. test.userId print is giving a value inside the loop but when i print the count the value is nil , apparently the values are not being saved correctly.

Comment: There is no declaration of `testing` array also `let test: Test = Test()!` should be inside the for loop.

Comment: Declaration of testing at the top of the page : var testing:[Test]?

Comment: Is that testing array is an Test array? and do you append test data at the bottom of for loop? Can we see the whole for loop if posible

Comment: You are definitely using too many exclamation and question marks. The array seems to contain non-optional strings. If you declare the array as `[String]()` you get rid of all type casts, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know variable s is relevant with your problem but I think it should work like this

```
 var testing:[Test]?

 for i in 0 ..< self.array.count{

    let test: Test = Test()
    test.userId = self.array[0] as! String?
    print(test.userId)
    test.firstName = self.array[1] as! String?
    test.lastName = self.array[2] as! String?
    test.img1 = self.array[3] as! String?
    test.img2 = self.array[4] as! String?
    test.img3 = self.array[5] as! String?
    test.featuredImg1 = self.array[6] as! String?
    test.url1 = self.array[7] as! String?
    test.featuredImg2 = self.array[8] as! String?
    test.url2 = self.array[9] as! String?
    test.featuredImg3 = self.array[10] as! String?
    test.url3 = self.array[11] as! String?
    test.userId2 = self.array[12] as! String?
    test.firstName2 = self.array[13] as! String?
    test.lastName2 = self.array[14] as! String?
    test.img4 = self.array[15] as! String?
    test.img5 = self.array[16] as! String?
    test.img6 = self.array[17] as! String?
    test.featuredImg4 = self.array[18] as! String?
    test.url4 = self.array[19] as! String?
    test.featuredImg5 = self.array[20] as! String?
    test.url5 = self.array[21] as! String?
    test.featuredImg6 = self.array[22] as! String?
    test.url6 = self.array[23] as! String?

    self.s = self.s! + 24

    //this is where your array is filled with test data.
    testing.append(test)

}
```

Test Class :

```
class Test
{
    var userId: String?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var img1: String?
    var img2: String?
    var img3: String?
    var featuredImg1: String?
    var url1: String?
    var featuredImg2: String?
    var url2: String?
    var featuredImg3: String?
    var url3: String?
    var userId2: String?
    var firstName2: String?
    var lastName2: String?
    var img4: String?
    var img5: String?
    var img6: String?
    var featuredImg4: String?
    var url4: String?
    var featuredImg5: String?
    var url5: String?
    var featuredImg6: String?
    var url6: String?

    init() {

    }


}
```

Comment: Did not work. I dont know if the problem is in saving the values.

Comment: are you sure your self.array is not empty and your test variable gets the right data?

Comment: The array is empty , i  checked again and testing.append(test) is not saving the values.

Comment: @yasserh then your test variable is empty. did you check the count of testing array. It is zero or same as self.array.count but empty elements?

Comment: the test array count is 48 , test.anyvalue is not empty , testing array is empty

Comment: Seems weird.Can you post your Test structure? Is it class or struct? And Why you need exclamation mark at Test()!

Comment: edited the post and i don't need the exclamation mark anymore

Comment: Your init() function is empty. Can you pass data to your Test properties at init function instead of reaching them directly. And can you change de array definition to var testing: [Test] = []  to get rid of question mark.